# Fragments recreated with Jetpack's Android Navigation components

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I have two fragments (for ex. fragmentA and fragmentB).

first , in fragmentA  use `findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB)` to navigate to fragmentB .

then , in fragmentB if you want to back to fragmentA. there are two ways in below :

- **just press back button** : fragmentA's `onCreate()` won't be called
- **findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentB_to_fragmentA)** : fragmentA's `onCreate()` will be called

**why?**

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the back button doesn't call onCreate of the fragment is by design. Users would not expect the back button to call the onCreate, or create, your fragment again.

As an example, think about when you open the YouTube app on Android and you are shown your home screen, populated with videos based on your interests. When you tap on a video after a bit of scrolling and then midway through the video decide to go back by pressing the back button, you expect the app to go back where you tapped on the video, with the same amount of scrolling you had done, instead of reloading your entire home page again filling with new videos and resetting you to the top of the screen.

Similarly, back button in your app should do the same. If however, you want your back button to behave differently, android does provide a way to do this. Refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) for that.

Comment: `The reason that the back button doesn't call onCreate of the fragment is by design. ` Is there any official Android documentation?